Measuring frontage for parcels in ArcGIS Pro
I'd like to measure the frontage of parcels on their assessed street. I have done all the processing up until this point. Take my parcels, convert parcels to lines, split at vertices, and then select only lines which share a line segment with a right of way. Now I'm stuck at a issue where I'm unable to differentiate corner parcels. For example, in the image attached the parcel circled has frontages on Brewer Rd and Central St but it's assessed frontage should be Central St. My methods are unable to differentiate frontage by street. I have to do this for tens of thousands of parcels so manually selecting the line segment on the correct street isn't feasible for me to do.
I've thought about how I could turn my streets into polygons so they can be extended left and right to meet with the frontage line, then determining if the street matches the assessed frontage but I'm unsure how to do this. I'm unable to get a buffer on the road to work because the roads are different widths and since I would need their unique attributes by street name, the overlaps wouldn't be helpful.


Try generate near table with many neighbors. Transfer ids of street and parcel and delete nomatch records
